# Property 'books' does not exist on type 'typeof client'

Tags: angular, typescript, tsconfig

I'm using the Google Book Api, and I'm trying to add a book to a library using gapi.client, but I keep getting this error.
This is the request :

```
gapi.client.books.mylibrary.bookshelves.volumes.list({
    shelf: shelfId,
     q: book.id
});
```

I have  "@types/gapi.client.books": "^1.0.1", and in tsconfig.app.json I include it in the types

```
 "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./out-tsc/app",
    "types": ["gapi.client.books", "gapi", "gapi.auth2"]
  }
```

Can anyone help me please?

Comment: This is my first question on stack overflow. It didn't post the whole request  `gapi.client.books.mylibrary.bookshelves.volumes.list({shelf: shelfId, q: book.id});`

Answer (score 0):

If this is the package you need `@types/gapi.client.books`, installing it is sufficient to remove any type error, no need to apply any changes on `tsconfig.app.json` for this matter., if not make sure you search for the correct package-types library to use.

P.S.
it's more convenient to install such dependency as a development dependency
`npm i @types/gapi.client.books -D`